# VSCode Python/pylance hinting show variable instead of method

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, pylance

I'm using vscode for python programming.

I recognized that, if I assign a method to a variable, vscode hinting shows is as variable (which seems correct on first sight).

How can I change this behavior? I want that vscode hinting shows is as method not as variable (see screenshot)?

Code:

```python
import os
import logging, logging.config

class mylog:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logconf='/path/to/logging.ini'
        if os.path.isfile(logconf):
            logging.config.fileConfig(logconf)

        self.debug=logging.getLogger('debug').debug


log=mylog()

log.debug('debug log...')
```

[image: vscode shows variable instead of method]

Comment: that is correct. Btw, *methods are variables*. they are *class variables*. So if it is an instance variable, it isn't even a method.

Comment: Yeah I know that, that is not the problem.. I know it is just a cosmetic thing, but it is possible that vscode can highlight this a method instead as variable.. And if yes, how?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to see? And no, I doubt there is any way to make VS Code treat a non-method as a method other than by writing an extension or something

Comment: What is even the material difference in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the method to a variable, and the intellisense for python itself is correct.

Variable **self.debug** represents the return value of the method, and in this case, it is just the variable rather than the method. It doesn't have any problems, you're pursuing the wrong type of prompt.